# Rail 5 swap ActionDispatch::Reloader with a custom reloader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2, actiondispatch

We have a use case for mounting a mock engine to process sessions when developing locally in which a custom session middleware calls the mock engine via Net::http request when a request comes through.

When there is code change, the reloader is triggered and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/reloader.rb#L101) calls the `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` to start unloading. Then the request is pass down to our custom session middleware and the http request is fired.
**However since the http request calls to a mountable engine, it goes thought the same middlewares again** and the reloader unloads all the dependencies again which cause the first reload to timeout. So the goal is to be able to skip the reload for the second request.

I added the follow code to `ActionDispatch::Reloader` [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb#L11) and it does exactly what I wanted.

```
class Reloader < Executor
  def initialize(app, executor)
    super(app, executor)
  end

  def call(env)
    request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
    return @app.call(env) if skip_request?(request)
    super(env)
  end

  def skip_request?(request)        
    request.path_info.start_with?('/session')
  end
end
```

Then I want to make this cleaner figured to pull that out completely to a module and just do a swap like this from an initializer

```
app.config.middleware.swap(::ActionDispatch::Reloader, MyModule::CustomReloaderMiddleware)
```

Here is the module

```
require 'action_dispatch'

module MyModule
  class CustomReloaderMiddleware < ActionDispatch::Executor
    def initialize(app, executor)
      @app, @executor = app, executor
    end

    def call(env)
      request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
      return @app.call(env) if skip_request?(request)
      super(env)
    end

    def skip_request?(request)
      request.path_info.start_with?('/session')
    end
  end
end
```

But I ran into a couple issues.

`Uncaught exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)` from for the `initialize` in `MyModule`, when I starts the server. Then I tried the following

```
#1

def initialize(app, executor = nil)
  @app, @executor = app, executor
end

#2

def initialize(app, executor = nil)
  @app, @executor = app, ActiveSupport::Reloader
end
```

Both of them starts the service correctly and I see the request going through this middleware but it does not reload the code.. So I wondered what is the correct way of swapping ActionDispatch::Reloader with a custom reloader ?

Comment: Sorry, I've had limited blocks of free time lately, and never came back to dig into your issue. This sounds like a good solution. 

Comment: O no worry !! you have been a great help and I have learned so much from what you wrote !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your middleware's additional argument to the `swap` call:

```
app.config.middleware.swap(::ActionDispatch::Reloader, MyModule::CustomReloaderMiddleware, app.reloader)
```

That's the same argument given when `ActionDispatch::Reloader` is [first added](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7e3a0a947faeecee03d2714789084addbcf7e414/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L52) -- it's the application's reloader, which is a more specifically configured subclass of AS::Reloader (so you were on the right track).

Comment: That works !! Thank you so much !! Through this process I learned so much about the reloader. I guess it's a unique use case that we have calling a mock engine from a middleware or do you think the reloader should prevent the second reload ?

Comment: I still _think_ the second reload should be unnecessary -- because the first one should've gotten everything up to date -- in which case the second should be prevented just by not being tried... if it legitimately thinks it needs to reload again, though, I'm not sure what it should do: skipping means the inner request runs on known-outdated code, which could be very confusing. (Here I'm sure it's fine, because the chances that your dummy session handler have changed seem vanishingly small.)

Comment: The mock engine is a gem that we add on to the app for development so it wouldn't ever have a code change on the fly. I think the fact that we are calling the mock engine in the middleware is the issue. From looking at the debugger, it seems like the executor call `run!` on the reloader and pass the request down the next middleware before the reloading is complete.

Comment: That request to the mock engine from the middleware hit the middlewares from the top again as if a new requests comes in which then unload all the classes and never make it out the middleware and cause the first request to timeout

Comment: When `run!` returns, the reload is done. (`complete!` is talking about the request that _triggered_ the reload, not the reload itself. Confusing naming )

Comment: `complete!` is the one that calls `self.class.reloaded!` which marks `@should_reload = false` But that is call after `@app.call(env)` which pass the request down the middleware. Although the reloading part is done and `release_unload_lock!` is called, but `@should_reload` was not mark as false until `complete!`

Comment: Oh! That makes sense, thanks. Seems tricky to solve for the general case (there are some configurations where the actual reloading happens in `complete!`), but that does sound like something worth fixing.

Comment: O .. i am not aware that there is config to make the reloading happens in 'complete! '. Do u know what is it call ?  I guess it would be some kind of call back. Not sure what that use case is but i am not sure thats a good idea with our case,  cuz reloading in 'complete! ' means that the middleware request will hit the old code. But anyhow I am more than happy to submit a pr with your guidance !!

Comment: But what is the reason to call '@app.call(env)' which pass the request down the middlewares after reloading is done but before 'complete!' is called ?? Then whats the reason wrapping the reloader with a executor at all ?